# MySQL CONCAT multiple unique rows

Tags: mysql

So, here's basically the problem:
For starter, I am not asking anyone to do my homework, but to just give me a nudge in the right direction.
I have 2 tables containing names and contact data for practicing
Let's call these tables `people` and `contact`.
Create Table for `people`:

> CREATE TABLE `people` (
>   `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `fname` tinytext,
>   `mname` tinytext,
>   `lname` tinytext,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Create Table for `contact`:

> CREATE TABLE `contact` (
>   `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `person_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>   `tel_home` tinytext,
>   `tel_work` tinytext,
>   `tel_mob` tinytext,
>   `email` text,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`person_id`),
>   KEY `fk_contact` (`person_id`),
>   CONSTRAINT `fk_contact` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `people` (`id`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

When getting the contact information for each person, the query I use is as follows:
`SELECT p.id, CONCAT_WS(' ',p.fname,p.mname,p.lname) name, c.tel_home, c.tel_work, c.tel_mob, c.email;`
This solely creates a response like:

```
+----+----------+---------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
| id | name     | tel_home            | tel_work | tel_mob | email               |
+----+----------+---------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 | Jane Doe | 1500 (xxx-xxx 1500) | NULL     | NULL    | janedoe@example.com |
|  2 | John Doe | 1502 (xxx-xxx 1502) | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                |
|  2 | John Doe | NULL                | NULL     | NULL    | johndoe@example.com |
+----+----------+---------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
```

The problem with this view is that row 1 and 2 (counting from 0) could've been grouped to a single row.
Even though this "non-pretty" result is due to corrupt data, it is likely that this will occur in a multi-node database environment.
The targeted result would be something like

```
+----+----------+---------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
| id | name     | tel_home            | tel_work | tel_mob | email               |
+----+----------+---------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 | Jane Doe | 1500 (xxx-xxx 1500) | NULL     | NULL    | janedoe@example.com |
|  2 | John Doe | 1502 (xxx-xxx 1502) | NULL     | NULL    | johndoe@example.com |
+----+----------+---------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
```

Where the rows with the same `id` and `name` are grouped when still showing the effective data.
Side notes:
innodb_version: 5.5.32
version: 5.5.32-0ubuntu-.12.04.1-log
version_compile_os: debian_linux-gnu

Comment: What if two or more records within a "group" contain conflicting data?

Comment: Non-NULL values should not be grouped together with other non-NULL values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), which "*returns a string result with the concatenated non-`NULL` values from a group*":

```
SELECT   p.id,
         GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ',p.fname,p.mname,p.lname)) name,
         GROUP_CONCAT(c.tel_home) tel_home,
         GROUP_CONCAT(c.tel_work) tel_work,
         GROUP_CONCAT(c.tel_mob ) tel_mob,
         GROUP_CONCAT(c.email   ) email
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: Basically, it does the job, except that it becomes a comma-seperated list when multiple non-NULL values occur inside one group.
(This could easily be fixed inside a procedural language, but I never mentioned one)